# How best to keep my localhost on Http while my Remote production is on Https

Tags: wp-cli, https, local-installation, development-strategy, production

I am using a plugin `**Really Simple SSL**` that configured to use SSL. And I use WP Migrate Pro to move my DB from local to remote. But I usually run into the problem of `pulling` the DB from productions to localhost during development, most of my links on the localhost are using https.

I do not want to set SSL on my local development.

Presently, I deactivate the **plugin Really Simple SSL** using `wp cli'. Next, I have to Find and Replace https to http on the localhost. That makes updates to be using unsecured repos and my fonts, css and cdn use http which create a new **security risk** for my development which would eventually end on in production.

What is the best approach so that I do not expose my production to security risk after development?

Comment: Why do you not want to use SSL on local? Keep in mind that you don't need an SSL plugin, you can set the sites URL option to use `https`, as long as your content uses `https` URLs and you're not using `http` hardcoded  in your theme everything's fine. I've never needed t install a plugin like Really Simple SSL. The real answer is to use HTTPS everywhere

Comment: @TomJNowell you advice I use https in the `wp-config` file. But some plugin do not go over SSL, and development because bad when the network is not very good.

Comment: That's not the same as what I suggested. Why are you insisting on no https locally?

Comment: Then you need to contact the plugin authors, those are very poorly built plugins ( or it's because you did not set up SSL and used a plugin to "fix" it )

Comment: On production, I setup SSL and AWS needs that particular plugin as part of the process of setup the SSL. [here](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress). On my local dev, I do not need it. Based on experience, it speeds up my development.

Comment: **That's not true.** Really Simple SSL just buffers the entire page then swaps the `http` to `https` on the fly so that users who don't know how to migrate to HTTPS properly can get a quick fix at the price of slowing their site down a bit. I know lots of sites hosted on AWS that do not use any SSL plugin at all. I guarantee it is not necessary. Whoever wrote that tutorial just included it to make it easier to follow for someone to migrate to SSL, when the truth is that by the time you reach step 8 you already have SSL, WP just isn't configured to use it

Comment: I would also argue that you do need it, there is a whole raft of technologies that impact development that are only available on HTTPS, e.g. HTTP2 push, multiplexing, etc, and a tonne of things that can't be tested with HTTP, such as mixed content warnings and various browser behaviours. With HTTP2 it should mean faster page loads as well due to faster handshakes, multiplexing, etc. You open yourself to accidentally building security holes by developing in HTTP while keeping production in HTTP2. If it slows you down then that implies you're using poor tooling to set it up

Comment: @TomJNowell, I would test your recommendation and get it the right way. And inform the person that wrote the tutorial. The argument is accepted.

Comment: This article covers what you need to do, if you've followed that tutorial you linked to then the certbot step has already been done, so just focus on the WordPress parts: https://websitesetup.org/http-to-https-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

The **correct** approach is to use HTTPS everywhere, and to migrate to SSL properly:

- remove the Really Simple SSL plugin
- change your sites URL option to the https version
- search replace your database so all content uses the https URL via WP CLI or a search replace tool ( do not use an SQL query it will break things )
- update any hardcoded strings in your theme from http to https

Then finally:

- set up a local SSL certificate and trust it in your browser

A lot of local dev environments will generate the certificate automatically, e.g. VVV or Local.

The alternative is a **painful** manual search replace each and every time you pull changes down, and push changes up.